# how to get individual user API by using django rest framework knox

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, token

Before I implement token authentication, it worked fine to grab each user,

```
GET: http://localhost:8000/users/1/  
 {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/users/1/",
        "id": 1,
        "username": "foo",
        "boards": [
            "http://localhost:8000/boards/15/"
        ]
    },
```

After I implement `knox` token authentication,

```py
#settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',),
}

#users/views.py
class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.use

#users/urls.py
app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', UserList.as_view(), name='user-list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', UserDetail.as_view(), name='user-detail'),
    path('accounts/register/', RegistrationAPI.as_view(), name='user-register'),
    path('accounts/login/', LoginAPI.as_view(), name='user-login'),
    path('accounts/logout/', knox_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='user-logout'),

]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)

# users/serializer.py
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    boards = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name='board:board-detail',
        lookup_field='pk',
        many=True, 
        queryset=Board.objects.all()
    )
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        read_only=True,
        lookup_field='pk',
        view_name="users:user-detail")


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'username', 'boards')

class CreateSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        read_only=True,
        lookup_field='pk',
        view_name="users:user-detail")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            validated_data['username'], None, validated_data['password']
        )
        return user
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'username', 'password')

class LoginUserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        user = authenticate(**data)
        if user and user.is_active:
            return user
        raise serializers.ValidationError("unable to log in with provided credential")

# project/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('boards/', include('apps.board.urls', namespace='board')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('apps.users.urls', namespace='users')), # detail of users
    path(r'^users/accounts/', include('knox.urls')), # detail of users
]
```

Now I am getting `401` error,

```
GET: http://localhost:8000/users/1/
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

Even, `POST:http://localhost:8000/logout/` has the same 401 Unauthorized error. I tried `login` first and then `logout`, but I still get same error. Why am I getting unauthorized
**EDIT**
Once I POST login, I got token and I pass this token to the header to 
1) GET individual user(http://localhost:8000/users/1/,
2) POST logout(http://localhost:8000/users/accounts/logout/
But I still get same `401 Unauthorized` status

Comment: How do you provide authorization headers after you log in?

Comment: @AndreyNelubin I am a new to APIs, so don't understand when you are saying `provide authorization header`. I use Postman and it takes care of. I just pass username and password to login and it gives me back 200 status.

Comment: Login returns token in response data, You need to pass it to headers in future requests. Take a look in the DRF token authorization docs for examples

Comment: @AndreyNelubin I got token when I request POST login, then pass it to the header Post logout. but still same 401 unauthorized error.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who just starts using Postman,

1. Get token when POST login
2. Switch mode to GET
3. In Headers session, Key: Authorization Value: Token xxxxx (token from step1)

then send this request.